# How to Loop Through OLAP Pivot table Filters in vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I Am new to VBA. I have Excel files which have some pivot tables created by connecting to OLAP Cubes.

I Need help on how to Loop through the filter column in the Pivot Tables the same How I loop through the Row Fields, column Fields & Data Fields as described in following code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsheet As Worksheet
    Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
    Dim pvtFld As PivotField
    Dim wsmapping As Worksheet

    ' Set the Variable Values
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsmapping = Worksheets("Mapping")

    'WorkBook Active sheets
    For Each wsheet In wb.Worksheets
        'Current Worksheet Pivot Table
        For Each PvtTbl In wsheet.PivotTables

            'Current Pivot Table Row Fields
            For Each PvtRowFld In PvtTbl.RowFields
                PvtRowFldName = PvtRowFld.Name
                RowFldPos = PvtRowFld.Position
                RowField = Left(PvtRowFldName, InStrRev(PvtRowFldName, ".") - 1)

                NewRowField = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RowField, wsmapping.Range("A2:B10"), 2, False), "No Mapping")
                'MsgBox NewPvtfld

                If NewRowField <> "No Mapping" Then
                    PvtTbl.CubeFields(RowField).Orientation = xlHidden

                    With PvtTbl.CubeFields(NewRowField)
                        .Orientation = xlRowField
                        .Position = RowFldPos
                    End With
                End If
            Next PvtRowFld

            'Current Pivot Table Column Fields
            For Each PvtColFld In PvtTbl.ColumnFields
                PvtColFldName = PvtColFld.Name
                ColFldPos = PvtColFld.Position
                ColField = Left(PvtColFldName, InStrRev(PvtColFldName, ".") - 1)
                NewColField = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ColField, wsmapping.Range("A2:B10"), 2, False), "No Mapping")
                MsgBox NewColField

                If NewColField <> "No Mapping" Then
                    PvtTbl.CubeFields(ColField).Orientation = xlHidden

                    With PvtTbl.CubeFields(NewColField)
                        .Orientation = xlColumnField
                        .Position = ColFldPos
                    End With
                End If
            Next PvtColFld

            'Current Pivot Table Measure
            For Each PvtMeasure In PvtTbl.DataFields
                PvtMeasureName = PvtMeasure.Name
                PvtMeasurePos = PvtMeasure.Position

                NewMeasureName = Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(PvtMeasureName, wsmapping.Range("A2:B10"), 2, False), "No Mapping")
                MsgBox NewMeasureName

                If NewColField <> "No Mapping" Then
                    PvtTbl.CubeFields(PvtMeasureName).Orientation = xlHidden

                    With PvtTbl.CubeFields(NewMeasureName)
                        .Orientation = xlDataField
                        .Position = PvtMeasurePos
                    End With
                End If
            Next PvtMeasure

            'Current Pivot Table Active Filters
            For Each pvtFilter In PvtTbl.ActiveFilters
                MsgBox pvtFilter.Name
            Next pvtFilter
        Next PvtTbl  
    Next wsheet
End Sub
```

In the Above code `PvtTbl.ActiveFilters`  For each loop is not Looping the Pivot table filter fields, Though I have many Active filters on the Pivot Table.

I see some references to `PvtTbl.PivotFields` which is looping through all the fields like rows, columns, Measures and Filters too. Using this I couldn't able to find that where the field is coming from whether it is from column/row/filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter fields above a pivot table are also `PivotFields` which are used as `PageField`.

As the term "filter" is something different (e. g. filtering each pivotfield additionally), I suggest to use another name for it, e. g. "pvtPageField".

You may reference it either as `PivotTable.PageField` or as `PivotTable.CubeField`, when its `Orientation` is `xlPageField`:

```
' simple approach:
Dim pvtPagefield As PivotField
For Each pvtPagefield In PvtTbl.PageFields
    Debug.Print pvtPagefield.Name
    Debug.Print pvtPagefield.Value
    Debug.Print pvtPagefield.SourceName
    Debug.Print pvtPagefield.Caption
Next pvtPagefield

' better approach:
Dim pvtCubeField As CubeField
For Each pvtCubeField In PvtTbl.CubeFields
    If pvtCubeField.Orientation = xlPageField Then
        Debug.Print pvtCubeField.Position
        Debug.Print pvtCubeField.Name
        Debug.Print pvtCubeField.Value
        Debug.Print pvtCubeField.Caption
        For Each pvtPagefield In pvtCubeField.PivotFields
            Debug.Print pvtPagefield.Name
            Debug.Print pvtPagefield.Value
            Debug.Print pvtPagefield.SourceName
            Debug.Print pvtPagefield.Caption
        Next pvtPagefield
    End If
Next pvtCubeField
```

---

I also suggest to use `Option Explicit`as first code line of ***every*** module.
That enforces a `Dim` of every variable, e. g.

```
Dim pvtFld As PivotField, PvtRowFld As PivotField, PvtColFld As PivotField
Dim PvtRowFldName As String, RowField As String, RowFldPos As Variant, NewRowField As String
Dim PvtColFldName As String, ColField As String, ColFldPos As Variant, NewColField As String
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. When I use PageFields can loop through the Filter Fields. Only Issue I had is I wasn't able to find the current position of the filter Filed.

Comment: I added more info about the cubefield, where you can also get the position.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Cube fields will refer from OLAP cube Where as pageFields will get refer from the Pivot table. correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am trying to understand the CubeFields. I have created a pivot table with the Some Fields and later one of the column has removed from the OLAP Cube. In this Scenario will it read the Pivot table Column which is removed from the OLAP Cube.

Comment: Yes, `CubeFields` refer to the cube and `PivotFields` to the pivot table - but they are connected. You can refer back and forth, e. g. `PivotField.CubeField` or `CubeField.PivotFields()`. If you rename a pivotfield, its new `Caption` differs from its `SourceCaption`. If you delete a cube column, the correspondig pivotfields are also deleted after a pivottable refresh.